# onClickListner in RecyclerViewer

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to have all Items to go to a defferent Activity. 
So Pizza Asterix is going to "Pizza_Asterix.xml".

For example the item "Pizza Asterix"

```
mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Asterix", "€7,00", "Tomatensaus, kaas en ananas"));
```

When you click on this item it wil go to antoher Activity

But I don't know how to start. And every YouTube video uses other coding.
Please help me...
Thanks in advance.
(I'm really new to coding an app)

Menu.java

```
package com.opzet.pizzaria.opzet;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListner{
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static final String GERECHT = "ImageView";
    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "Text1";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR = "Text2";
    public static final String EXTRA_LIKES = "Text3";




    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    Button show;



    Dialog MyDialog;
    Button close,kinder,voor,salades,soepen,diversen,pasta,alles,pizza,penette,ravioli,oven,rijst,vlees,vis,afronden;




































    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);





    show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                MyCustomAlertDialog();

            }


        });


    afronden = (Button)findViewById(R.id.afronden);
        afronden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openAfronden();
            }
        });



        createExampleList();


        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

    }




































    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {
            if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {
            if (item.getText3().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {
            if (item.getText2().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }





        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }





    private void createExampleList() {





















        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();



        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Asterix", "€7,00", "Tomatensaus, kaas en ananas"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Obelix", "€7,00", "Tomatensaus, kaas en jam"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Idefix", "€7,50", "Tomatensaus, kaas, ham en ananas"));












        mRecyclerView =

                findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }



    public void MyCustomAlertDialog(){
        MyDialog = new Dialog(Menu.this);
        MyDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        MyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
        MyDialog.setTitle("My Custom Dialog");

        soepen = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.soepen);
        close = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        kinder = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.kinder);
        voor = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.voor);
        salades = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.salades);
        diversen = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.diversen);
        pasta = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.pasta);
        alles = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.alles);
        pizza = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.pizza);
        penette = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.pennette);
        ravioli = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.ravioli);
        oven = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.oven);
        rijst = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.rijst);
        vlees = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.vlees);
        vis = MyDialog.findViewById(R.id.vis);


        soepen.setEnabled(true);
        close.setEnabled(true);
        kinder.setEnabled(true);
        voor.setEnabled(true);
        salades.setEnabled(true);
        diversen.setEnabled(true);
        pasta.setEnabled(true);
        alles.setEnabled(true);
        pizza.setEnabled(true);
        penette.setEnabled(true);
        ravioli.setEnabled(true);
        oven.setEnabled(true);
        rijst.setEnabled(true);
        vlees.setEnabled(true);
        vis.setEnabled(true);


        soepen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSoepen();
            }
        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        kinder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openKinder();
            }
        });

        voor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openVoor();
            }
        });

        salades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openKinder();
            }
        });

        diversen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDiversen();
            }
        });

        pasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPasta();
            }
        });

        salades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSalades();
            }
        });




        alles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openAlles();
            }
        });

        pizza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPizza();
            }
        });

        penette.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPenette();
            }
        });

        ravioli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openRavioli();
            }
        });

        oven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOven();
            }
        });

        rijst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openRijst();
            }
        });


        vlees.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openVlees();
            }
        });

        vis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openVis();
            }
        });

































        MyDialog.show();
    }





    public void openKinder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kinder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVoor() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Voor.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openSoepen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Soepen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openDiversen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diversen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openPasta() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pasta.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openSalades() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pasta.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void openAlles() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void openPizza() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, pizza.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void openPenette() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, penette.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openRavioli() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ravioli.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openRijst() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, rijst.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVlees() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, vlees.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVis() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, vis.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openOven() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, oven.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void openAfronden() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bestelling.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, POPUP.class);
        ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickedItem.getText1());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR, clickedItem.getText2());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_LIKES, clickedItem.getText3());
        detailIntent.putExtra(GERECHT, clickedItem.getImageResource());


    }
}
```

ExampleItem.java

```
package com.opzet.pizzaria.opzet;






public class ExampleItem {
private int mImageResource;
private String mText1;
private String mText2;
private String mText3;










public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2, String 
text3) {
    mImageResource = imageResource;

    mText1 = text1;
    mText2 = text2;
    mText3 = text3;


}















public int getImageResource() {
    return mImageResource;
}

public String getText1() {
    return mText1;
}

public String getText2() {
    return mText2;
}

public String getText3() {
    return mText3;
}





























}
```

ExampleAdapter.java

```
package com.opzet.pizzaria.opzet;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ExampleAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private OnItemClickListner mListner;

public interface OnItemClickListner{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}


public void SetOnItemClickListner(OnItemClickListner listner) {
    mListner = listner;
}


public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;
    public TextView mTextView3;







    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListner listner) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mListner != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listner.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }

        });



    }
}

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
    mExampleList = exampleList;
}





@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,
            parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListner);
    return evh;





}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);



    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    holder.mTextView3.setText(currentItem.getText3());





}








@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}





public void filterList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList) {
    mExampleList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}






}
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.opzet.pizzaria.opzet.MainActivity"
android:focusable="true"

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/boven"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rechthoekboven"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="210dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/Menukaart"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="240dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sorteerbalk"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="84dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/boven"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zoekbalk"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/zoekbalk"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zoekbalk"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/sorteren"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="240dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="Zoeken..."/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/show"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button"
    android:alpha="0"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sorteerbalk"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bestelling" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/afronden"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView9"
    android:alpha="0"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ExampleItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Line 1"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:text="Line 3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageADD"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageADD"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:alpha="0"/>


</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: your questions is not clear, can you please explain a bit more what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to have for example the Item:                                                                                                
                                                                        
mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fotogerecht, "Pizza Asterix", "€7,00", "Tomatensaus, kaas en ananas"));                                           
                                                                                                     
have an onClickListner... so when you tap on the Item it will go to antoher Activity.

Comment: Please minimize and tidy your code before posting here. Surely not all of that code is necessary to show a basic `RecyclerView` setup, and the large blocks of whitespace are definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way,

give an id to exampleItem.xml relativeLayout

then make reference to that item inside ExampleViewHolder

> android:id="@+id/relativelayout1";

reference the linearlayout in ExampleViewHolder

```
public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListner listner) {
relativelayout = itemview.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
}
```

then setonclick listener on relativelayout

```
 @Override     
 public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) { 

 holder.relativelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override                 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(context,NextActivity.class); 
                 startactivity(i);      
                 // you can also pass position of item in intent extra    
              } });}
```

if this work you don't need to implement onclicklistener to activity. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: ok do it inside onbindviewholder, you get the position of item clicked which you can use to track down which item was clicked in the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understand what is your want but for you put simple code , I hope help you

I'm use butter Knife you can see more this link
http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

```
public static class MenuVM extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            @BindView(R.id.Dashboard_menu_txt)
            public TextView txt_item;
            @BindView(R.id.Dashboard_menu_ll_item)
            public LinearLayout ll_menu;
            @BindView(R.id.Dashboard_menu_img_line_up)
            public ImageView line_up_item;
            @BindView(R.id.Dashboard_menu_img_line_down)
            public ImageView line_down_item;
            @BindView(R.id.dashboard_menu_img)
            public ImageView dashboard_menu_img;

            public MenuVM(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            }
        }


public static class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuVM> {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Menu_Model> menu_models;

        public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Menu_Model> menu_models) {
            this.context = context;
            this.menu_models = menu_models;
        }

        @Override
        public MenuVM onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_menu_item, parent, false);
            MenuVM viewHolder = new MenuVM(view2);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MenuVM holder, int position) {
            final Menu_Model model = menu_models.get(position);
            holder.txt_item.setText(model.getTitle());

            holder.ll_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickItem(model.getTitle());
                }
            });
        }

        private void onClickItem(String title) {
            startActivty(context,YouActivty.class);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return menu_models.size();
        }
    }
```

dashboard_menu_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/Dashboard_menu_ll_item"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   ....

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an `OnClickListener` inside of your `ViewHolder` You should instead set the listener inside of your binder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    holder.mTextView3.setText(currentItem.getText3());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class); 
           startactivity(intent);
           // Do activity transition here, or trigger listener to do it
           // You already have the position
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For RecyclerView Touch Listener :

```
public class RecyclerTouchListner implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListner(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

and Finally in your  Activity Class:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListner(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListner.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                ExampleItem list = exampleItemobject.get(position);
                String id = list.getsId();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           // DO YOUR INTENT HERE WITH NECCESSARY DATA


            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```